# Share WiFi connection via the Ethernet port on Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

How can I share the Internet signal a Windows 8 PC receives via the WiFi adapter thru the Ethernet port to another device that does not have a WiFi adapter?

In other words, the Windows 8 PC connects to the internet via a wireless connection, and I'd like to share that connection to my DirecTV receiver which does not have a WiFi card (only an Ethernet port).

Answer (score 0):

"...share that connection to my DirecTV receiver which does not have a WiFi card (only an Ethernet port)." - so in other words you will have to use a RJ45 cable running to the wifi-router? I assume the DirecTV receiver cannot use wireless connection for internet. So then the only option as mentioned is a RJ 45 cable.

Comment: So I'd have to plug an RJ45 cable, sound fair. But it's not a router, but the Ethernet port on the computer. I'd like to share the Internet the computer is getting via the Wi-Fi, out thru the ethernet port to the DirecTV Receiver.

Comment: Not going to work. The source of your internet connection is the Wifi router right? That is where your computer gets internet connectivity (wireless) from. The ethernet port cannot operate as a switchport - therefore you would need to take the cable to your Wifi router and plug it in there. EXCEPT if you are using a dongle or 3G technology, but then Im not sure if the whole scenario is possible.